# Not able to write the message into excel file in console showing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, file, apache-poi

public void write(int row1, int cell1, String message, String sheet1) throws Throwable {

```
    String path = ".\\resources\\APItestdata.xlsx";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    //File fis=new File(path);
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheet1);
    Row r = sh.getRow(row1);
    Cell c = r.createCell(cell1);
    c.setCellValue(message);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
    wb.write(fos);
    wb.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace tells you what code line throws the `NullPointerException`. So what code line is `ExcelLibrary.java:45`, code line 45 in ExcelLibrary.java?

I suspect it is `Cell c = r.createCell(cell1);`. So `r` is `null`. That's possible because [Sheet.getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow-int-) returns the row representing the row-number **or null if its not defined on the sheet**.

So do some null checks:

```
...
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("sheet1");
    if (sh == null) sh = wb.createSheet("sheet1");
    Row r = sh.getRow(row1);
    if (r == null) r = sh.createRow(row1);
    Cell c = r.createCell(cell1);
    c.setCellValue(message);
...
```